# What language has been used to create Python?

Tags: python, programming-languages

Which programming language has been used to develop Python (programming language) ?

Thank you

Comment: Wow. It took you more effort to answer this homework question by re-asking it on StackOverflow than it would have taken to ask a search engine and get the right answer. Well done!

Comment: +1 for the above comment

Comment: @Nam: It's an impressive effort and should be applauded. Really going the extra mile. Hopefully the teacher will award extra points for initiative.

Answer (score 12):

The most-often used implementation is written in C and called "CPython". It can be downloaded at the main [Python website](http://python.org/).

There are also implementations written in Java ([Jython](http://jython.org/)) and C# ([IronPython](http://ironpython.net/)) and Python ([PyPy](http://pypy.org/)).

Answer (score 4):

C Programming Language and others

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_(programming_language)